# Is there a way to auto logout user with when there is no activity using Flask(Python)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to auto logout the user if there is no activity for a set interval of time using Python-Flask.
Thank you.

Comment: good luck. And next time describe problem in question's body, not in question's title.

Comment: You could check whether their session has expired with each request.

Comment: in flask you can only check if login cookie is still valid when user will load next page and then send page with message that he is logged out. But if you want to inform user without loading next page then you will need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

before_request decorator allows you to create function that will run before each request.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    # Maybe add an attribute "flag" on User table ? 
    users = User.query.all()
    for user in users:
        if user.flag == true:
            logout(user)
```